# Voltage measure problem in charge controller

Tags: microcontroller, battery-charging, solar-energy

1: I not understand the procedure of measuring SOLAR and BATTERY voltages. The time the MOSFET Q1 ON, the voltage will be nearly the same on solar and Battery side even if we start to charge the battery from low voltage level...so how could we measure the battery and solar voltage separately while MOSFET is ON???
I thought that we might measure the voltage of battery in zero period of the input PWM signal but is this time enough for adc and to make battery return to its actual voltage level.?? my pwm frequency is 700KHZ and Clock Speed is 4MHZ..[image]
2: And one more thing If PV negative pass through the MOSFET, during the MOSFET OFF period PV ground and BAT ground disconnect. Will the microcontroller read PV-ADC accurately …??
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You probably cant.

Since that mosfet is being turned on and off rapidly by whatever is controlling it, the controller probably reads the value during the off phase of the PWM cycle. As for time to settle, assuming the micro is controlling the PWM, it can take all the time in needs.

Your second schematic has a high side common, which though unusual, still passes the unloaded voltage reference to the PIC.

In this case though the value is referenced to Battery voltage. That is "Battery voltage" means the solar panel is "dark". A lower value would indicate how much voltage the panel is generating. Since you would need to offset the value based on that reference it is a rather odd way to do it.